# Store blocks of text in PHP variable

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I have a bunch of javascript files I need to parse via PHP (I don't want to push them to the browser; I want to do this fully in the backend), and they all contain a variable declaration, for example (actual content of one of the js files):

```
var x = '<html><div class="foo">blocks of text</div></html>';
```

Basically they all enclose html within single quotes, and the variable is always the same (x in this case).  What's the best way to extract everything inside the single quotes into a PHP variable?

edit: there's extra code at the end of each file generated (I am not generating the files by the way, it's done by a 3rd party):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 7')>-1){ x = x.replace(/([^>])<(\/?)span/g,'$1<wbr/><$2span'); }; jsonp_PageLoaded(1,0,x);
```

Comment: Does the file only have that one line or are there be multiple lines plus other syntax?

Comment: erisco: oh, also, the variable is just one line, but it could be one very long line if that matters.  then the extra syntax at end.

Comment: is the extra syntax on a separate line? that is, is the variable definition on its own, exclusive line?

Comment: erisco: no, it's all within the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out on my own.  Here's the code using PHP:

```
$str = file_get_contents('file.js');
$pattern = "/\'([^\']*)\';/";
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to rewrite them to javascript objects.

```
var object = {
  x: "<html>etc.</html>",
  y: "etc."
}
```

This can easily be parsed by json_decode.

Comment: I would love to, but I'm not writing the javascript files. I'm getting them dumped to me on a remote S3 bucket (via a 3rd party company) and I have to scoop up the multiple JS files and parse through them--unless you know of a very simple way to convert them?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the fastest but, what about reading the whole file in and using

```
$varDeclaration = 'var x = ';
$pos = strpos($str,$varDeclaration);
$start = $pos + strlen($varDeclaration);
$end = strpos($str,"\n",$start);

$string = substr($str, $start+1, ($end-$start)-3); // +1 and -3 is to account for the single quotes that wrap the string and the ending semi colon
```

Comment: What about when the string contains a semicolon itself?

Comment: hmm, didn't think about that, heh. You will have to use Regex then, which i am not the best with unfortunately. Is the variable dec the same everytime time? (Is it actually x?)

Comment: Actually, if the string is always one line (No new lines in it) the edit above should work.

Comment: yes, the variable dec is the same everytime, no, it's not actually "x", but I think that's irrelevant, since it's always the same.

Comment: hmm, not quite working for me; i am using: `$str = file_get_contents("file.js");` to get file contents.  I get the error: "Notice: Undefined variable: varDeclaration"

Comment: Sorry, i misspelled one of the variables (The first instance of varDeclaration) edited and fixed

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions.  The solution TJMonk15 gives might work, but regex is the "real" way to extract portions of arbitrary string data like that.

It's worth every programmers' time to learn regex.  Doesn't take long to get the basics, and definitely one of the things that separates beginners from more experienced folks.